# How to print __repr__ in a Python3 file? (not in shell)

Tags: python, shell, magic-methods, repr

I know that in Python Shell when you type `>>> object` it shows the `object.__repr__` method and if you type `>>> print(object)` it shows the `object.__str__` method.

But my question is, is there a short way to print `__repr__` while executing a Python file?

I mean, in a file.py if I use `print(object)` it will show `object.__str__` and if I just type `object` it shows nothing.

I have tried using `print(object.__repr__)` but it prints `<bound method object.__repr__ of reprReturnValue>`

Or is this impossible?

Comment: You need to actually call the method using `()`, e.g. `object.__repr__()`. Currently you are just referring to the method itself. A more appropriate call would be using the `repr()` builtin, e.g. `repr(object())`.

Comment: @AChampion that doesn't work. Everyone keeps suggesting this without testing it.

Comment: @AlexHall, not sure why you think this isn't correct. `class X(object): def __repr__(self): return 'Hello'; X().__repr__()` outputs the expected result as does `repr(X())`.

Comment: @AChampion I had assumed OP meant the actual meaning of `object`, not that he had shadowed the name with an instance.

Comment: Ahh, I assumed it was some generic reference because the base `object` type would print something if you just typed `object` in the interpreter. And `object.__repr__` would not be a bound method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to print the representation and nothing else, then

```
print(repr(object))
```

will print the representation. Where your invocation went wrong were the missing parentheses, as the following works as well:

```
print(object.__repr__())
```

If however you want this to be part of more information and you are using string formatting, you don't need to call `repr()`, you can use the conversion flag `!r`

```
print('The representation of the object ({0!r}) for printing,'
      ' can be obtained without using "repr()"'.format(object))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `repr(object)`.

```
print(repr(object))
```

Comment: @AlexHall I guess I was thinking of `__str__`. I fixed the answer.

Comment: `object.__str__()` doesn't work either if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @AlexHall are you sure?  I just created a class with a `__str__` method, and both `str(obj)` and `obj.__str__()` worked. And in fact so does `__repr__`.

Comment: My mistake, I had assumed OP meant the actual meaning of object, not that he had shadowed the name with an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print(some_object.__repr__())
```

`__repr__` needs to be called before you print it since it is a method unlike attributes such as `__file__`, `__name__`, etc., which do not need to be called (and cannot, for that matter). The same is true for the  `__str__()` method: you need to call it with - `some_object.__str__()`, not `some_object.__str__`.

I assumed that the OP was referring to a general object with the word `object`, rather than the actual Python object called `object`, so I have used the variable name `some_object` instead. As was pointed out in the comments, if you literally do `object.__repr__()` this will raise an exception since `__repr__()` must be called on the instance (i.e., `object().__repr__()` will work).

Comment: @AlexHall, I have tried it. Can you please explain how it is an error?

Comment: @AlexHall oh are you referring literally to the python object `object`? i assumed the OP was using `object` simply to refer to any object, i.e., a string, a list, etc.

Comment: Yes, I thought OP meant the actual type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old backticks

```
print(`object`)
```

in Python 2, or

```
print(repr(object))
```

in both Python 2 & 3